# Run ruby script from rake task

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rake

I have a small ruby script which runs just fine when I run it manually from the command line. It uses three gems which I have installed using "gem install X" and at the top of the script file I have the lines "require X". All works fine.

Now I am creating a task in Rake which will call my ruby script. I have tried to both use

```rb
system("/tools/myscript.rb #{foo} #{bar}")
```

and

```rb
`/tools/myscript.rb #{foo} #{bar}`
```

but both give me this error:

> myscript.rb:2:in `require': no such file to load -- ruby-audio
>   (LoadError)

It seems that the gem is not properly loaded. I tried to add the gems to the Gemfile of my Rails app but after all necessary gems had been added and I ran `bundle update` it ended in error with the mysql adapter not working from my script.

But since the script works just fine from the command line, I thought there really should be an easy way to call it from within the Rake task.

Any ideas?

Comment: Any particular reason why you don't integrate the Ruby code from the script into the task instead of shelling out and executing the script in a separate process?

Comment: Yes, 1) that particular code is shared with other stuff and 2) it will most likely be rewritten in C++ later on.

Answer (score 3):

Use

```
bundle exec <script>
```

To be sure to load the bundled Gems for the script you want to run

Comment: Tried both `bundle exec rake mytask` and `system("bundle exec myscript.rb #{foo} #{bar}")`. Neither made any difference.

Comment: could you give the output of `print \`("bundle list")\``? do you use RVM?

Comment: `sh: bundle list: not found`. Hadn't heard of RVM until you mentioned it. So unless Rails 3 uses it internally by default then I guess not.

Comment: I've just noted that my command wasn't well formatted (the back ` is used for code format in SO). Could you try again with

    `print %x(bundle list)`

Do you obtain the same result "not found"? If yes, I should think about it.

If you don't use RVM, it eliminates some options.

Comment: It gives me the same list as when I run `bundle list` from within my rails app directory. The gems needed for the script are not there. Btw, should I put this line in my task or in my script? I've put it in the task.

Comment: You did right by adding it in the task. Sorry to not have been enough clear on that point. Now we know that the script couldn't access to gem in the provided environment. I didn't realize that you installed it only globally. If you put the gem in your Gemfile, do a bundle intall, it should work. For the explanations why it didn't work when you installed the gem globally, it's because when you run the script `myscript.rb`, you do it in a shell, and in the environment of that shell you don't automatically have access to your global gems.

Comment: Yes, this is what I suspected. But in my original question I mentioned having tried the route of adding it to the Gemfile. I was wondering if I someone could "reset" the shell environment when I call my script from my task so that the script gets access to the gems I installed globally.

Comment: Ok you need to pass the environment variables GEM_HOME and GEM_PATH to the shell. I see two possible solutions (I've tried both but not sure my system is similar to yours). 1/ `%x(/bin/bash -c "bundle exec <scriptname>")` 2/ `system({"GEM_HOME" => "<gem_home path>", "GEM_PATH" => "<gem_path>"}, "<scriptname path>")`

Comment: First solution: same issue as before (missing gems) but also a lot of output seems to get suppressed, making it hard to know what's going on sometimes. Second solution: "cannot convert Hash into String". Ruby 1.8.

Comment: 2nd solution is only possible since 1.9. Well, let's try the following in your rake task `ENV['GEM_PATH'] = "<your gem_path>"; ENV['GEM_HOME'] = "<your gem_home>"; system("/tools/myscript.rb #{foo} #{bar}")`